# Assigning of variables in parent class in c#

Tags: c#, variables, parent-child, abstract

I’m working with a state pattern and are wondering how to define variables so they can use in each child class. A protected variable in the abstract parent class may be the right choice, but with this, I’m wondering how to initialize these variables from the main class.

```
class Main
{
    \\Initialize variable "file" here?  
    \\...
            Context tc = new Context(new Step01());
    \\...
}


class Context
{
    private State ts;

    // Constructor
    public Context(State st)
    {
        this.State = st;
    }

    // Gets or sets the state
    public State State
    {
        get
        {
            return st;
        }
        set
        {
            st = value;
        }
    }

    public void Request()
    {  
       ts.Handle(this);
    }
}


abstract class State
{
    protected string file = "file";
    public abstract void Handle(Context tc);
}

class Step01 : State
{      
    tc.State = new Step02();
    // use variable "file"
}

class Step02 : State
{   
    tc.State = new Step0x()   
    // use variable "file"
}
```

The example is a code snipped and don't work. I hope it helps to explain my question more accurate.

The quantity of child classes (Step0x) varies, so I think it's easier to define the variable only once in the parent class.

Does anybody have an idea how to initialize my variables in the main class?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not initialize it in the abstract class's constructor? the fact that it's an abstract class doesn't mean you can't have a constructor for it...

Comment: Is  your question how to declare a variable so that all the State subclasses can use it?  Make sure you understand that the way you declared it, they will all have access to the "file" variable, but not to the same instance, so not necessarily the same value.

Comment: Defining it in the abstact works pretty well, but I try to find a way defining it in the main. This should keep it more simple because you only have to adapt the main, not the abstract. The value of “file” should be constant in all instances. It’s not necessary to change it.

Comment: If the value should be set from Main and shared between all instances inheriting the abstract base class, why not use a static property in the base class?

Comment: @Mr.Knackwurst - If the dependency is hard coded across all instances on State, you may prefer to add it to a configuration file and the base abstract class will simply read it from there.

Comment: @Amir: I like the idea of a configuration file... do you have an example.

Comment: @Zohar: How do I have access to the property from the main? I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: @Mr.Knackwurst - You create a configuration file per scope (environment or global) and simply read the configuration section that will contain the property.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173468/Four-Ways-to-Read-Configuration-Setting-in-Csharp

Comment: @Zohar: Got it, sorry for my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @ Amit: Thank you so much. I will check the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define file as constant:

```
abstract class State
{
    protected const string file = "file";
    public abstract void Handle();
}
```

Here is implementation of `Step01` and `Step02` which are using `file`:

```
class Step01 : State
{
    public override void Handle(){}            

    public void PrintFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("step1 + {0}", file));
    }
}

class Step02 : State
{
    public override void Handle(){}

    public void PrintFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("step2 + {0}", file));
    }
}
```

And here is usage of the `Step01` and `Step02` classes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Step01 step1 = new Step01();
    step1.PrintFile();
    Step02 step2 = new Step02();
    step2.PrintFile();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I have to add the property set to the abstract class to set the filename from the main function. That works perfectly for me.